# linkedin boot selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

hi i try  to write a bot that automates once a day. Logged into my LinkedIn chat with a person who sends me posts and every message i wiil have post and bot need to to respond my email and write send my you cv something similar to this.

```
def start():
    driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com")
    time.sleep(3)
    username = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'session_key')
    username.send_keys(MyUsername)
    time.sleep(0.7)
    password = driver.find_element(By.ID, "session_password")
    password.send_keys(MyPassword)
    time.sleep(0.3)
    button_sign = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@type="submit"]')
    button_sign.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    # scroll_down_random()
    button_messaging = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="global-nav"]/div/nav/ul/li[4]/a')
    button_messaging.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    search_chat = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="search-conversations"]')
    search_chat.send_keys(name_of_chat)
    search_chat.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(2)
    submit_application = driver.find_element(By.ID,'//*[@id="ember65"]')
    submit_application.click()
```

but I am stuck on two things one After I search I can't select the first chat and I Run in a loop between messages in posts.

after

```py
submit_application = driver.find_element(By.ID,'//*[@id="ember65"]')
submit_application.click()
```

need to click the first person after I search. and how I can sty always connected if I upload it to the cloud without having to connect every time

Comment: so where is the problem? whats not working? clarify the problem please.

Comment: I can not succeed in clicking on the first chat after the search
@RolandasUlevicius

Answer (score 0):

I think the ID you are searching for is incomplete, I get an ID like
"overlay-conversation-card-ember133"

This might be different for different devices so I believe you should use XPATH here rather than the ID.
Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**
It seems selenium .click() does not always register, use .submit() although this doesn't work for all browsers incase of that use .send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

Comment: I tried both through id and through XPATH. I changed the code    
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ember683"]/div[2]')
    element.click()|
I get error selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="ember683"]/div[2]"}

Comment: You need to change the XPATH too, how can selenium find XPATH using ID.
Please refer this for getting the XPATH:
https://youtu.be/mNpqZoZArt0
Then change the XPATH according to your element/preference

Comment: That's exactly what I did. And I also did a search this way and it works, but it doesn't work when clicking on the first result, that's exactly why I opened the question. You can try it yourself and put alone it doesn't work

Comment: Oh sorry!! It seems selenium .click() does not always register, use .submit() although this doesn't work for all browsers incase of that use .send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

Comment: I noticed that XPATH is changing

Comment: Try with ID as our main issue was .click() anyway, Please do tell me if it works!
As .submit() works for me

Comment: no every time id changing try run the code...

Comment: Try using something like this
`ul_list = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "msg-overlay-list-bubble-search__list-item display-flex align-items-center pv2 ph3")

items = ul_list.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "li")
items[0].submit()`

P.S. I haven't tested it,on Linkedin, but tried changing the details of the classes as you suggested.

Comment: yeah there could be a thing, where the ids or classnames change everytime (or sometimes). please refer to this page https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18342/how-to-handle-dynamic-changing-ids-in-xpath

Comment: @RolandasUlevicius ok but if what I search is dynamic so how can I know? like in linkedin open chat and all posts in conversation I insert and write Comment